# Creating a var referencing a store from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, redux

I am currently working on creating a var that references a store from redux. I created one but within the `render()`. I want to avoid that and have it called outside of the render. Here is an example of it. I was recommended on using `componentWillMount()`, but I am not sure how to use it. Here is a snippet of the code I implemented. Note: It works, but only when I render the data. I am using double JSON.parse since they are strings with \

```
  render() {

        var busData= store.getState().bus.bus;
        var driverData= store.getState().driver.gdriveras;
        var dataReady = false;

        if (busData&& driverData) {
            dataReady = true;
            console.log("========Parsing bus data waterout========");
            var bus_data_json = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(busData));
            console.log(bus_data_json);
            console.log("========Parsing driver data waterout========");
            var driver_data_json = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(driverData));
            console.log(driver_datat_json);

            busDatajson.forEach(elem => {
                elem.time = getFormattedDate(elem.time)
            });

            driverDatajson.forEach(elem => {
                elem.time = getFormattedDate(elem.time)
            });
            ...
        }
   }
```

Comment: You should read this https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: Can you give me an example, I am kinda confused. I read the connect() and componentWillMount() and they both seems great, but not sure how to implement this with a JSON.parse the redux store.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `react-redux` usage that will probably help you.
Don't forget to add `StoreProvider` to your top three component (often named `App`).

I warned you about the fact that `React` and `Redux` are not meant to be used by beginner javascript developer. You should consider learn about `immutability` and functional programming.

```
// ----

const driverReducer = (state, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case 'SET_BUS': // I assume the action type
      return {
        ...state,
        gdriveras: JSON.parse(action.gdriveras) // parse your data here or even better: when you get the response
      }
    // ...
  }

}

// same for busReducer (or where you get the bus HTTP response)
// you can also format your time properties when you get the HTTP response


// In some other file (YourComponent.js)
class YourComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      bus,
      drivers
    } = this.props

    if (!bus || !drivers) {
      return 'loading...'
    }

    const formatedBus = bus.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      time: getFormattedDate(item.time)
    }))

    const formatedDrivers = drivers.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      time: getFormattedDate(item.time)
    }))

    // return children

  }
}


// this add bus & drivers as props to your component
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  bus: state.bus.bus,
  drivers: state.driver.gdriveras
}) 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
// you have to add StoreProvider from react-redux, otherwise connect will not be aware of your store
```